# JMeter get specific node from testplan in java

Tags: java, jmeter

In my JMeter test file i have multiple user-defined-variables-nodes and i would like to activate or deactivate them under specific circumstances.
Therefore i need to get them as a JMeterTreeNode Object in Java. So instead of treeModel.getRoot(); i want something like treeModel.getNodeByName() so that my code could look somewhat like this:

```
JMeterTreeModel treeModel = new JMeterTreeModel(new Object());
JMeterTreeNode variablesNode= (JMeterTreeNode) treeModel.getNodeByName("jmeterNodeNameOrId");
if (true)        
{        
  variablesNode.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found a working solution. Dmitris answer led me to take a look at the jmx as the xml. UserDefinedVariables is a "Arguments" node.

So first of all i had to get the Arguments Section

```
SearchByClass searcher = new SearchByClass(Arguments.class);
testPlanTree.traverse(searcher); //testPlanTree is a param
Object[] o = searcher.getSearchResults().toArray();
return o[0] //just the first one
```

In another Method i could use this like

```
JMeterTreeModel treeModel = new JMeterTreeModel(new Object());
JMeterTreeNode root = (JMeterTreeNode) treeModel.getRoot();
treeModel.addSubTree(testPlanTree, root);
            
JMeterTreeNode argumentNode = treeModel.getNodeOf(getArgumentsMethodFromAbove(testPlanTree));
String vars = argumentNode.getTestElement().getName();
```

And then you can do things like

```
if (vars.equals("foo"))
{
   argumentNode.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You won't be able to "deactivate" a "node" in the runtime
2. Moreover [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) are processed before any JSR223 Test Element so all of them will be "activated" long before your code starts executing.

   > Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start.

The only way to "deactivate" the node is disabling it before the test starts, the most convenient way I can think of is [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation/) automation framework which:

- [Allows execution of JMX files](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File)
- and allows [arbitrary modifications of the existing JMX files](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) in the preprocessing phase

Comment: Thanks for you reply! As it is my goal to de(activate) nodes before start of the test, is there a solution to do this with java without using the framework?

Comment: I can think of at least 2 options: using Java XML API (JMeter .jmx files are normal XML files) or using JMeter API

Answer (score 0):

There are JMeter [enhancements](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65702) to add disabled/enable capabilities on runtime you can upvote or contribute to.

> Bug 65702 - Add field disabled on all component

Or [Bug 62495](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62495)

> Add option to disable View Results Tree/Listeners